# Android Studio : How to create a hidden folder in android Q

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

I am trying to save image in hidden mode , since we cannot touch external storage and make directory there , i was saving my images in Relative location that is Directory.Pictures with help of MediaStore through Content values

As we can make hidden folder by adding a dot at start of folder name but now in android 10 whenever i do it , Os change name automatic and add _ to folder name

For example .image is converted to _.image

So how can i make hidden folder?

Comment: Why are you adding anything to MediaStore if you want it to be hidden?

Comment: In android 10 we are not allowed to store in external storage